# List the elements of the following set:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

$\underline{4}= \{ {1, 2, 3, 4} \}$
[image]

$ \{a \in  \underline{4} :(\exists x \in \underline{4}) (R(a,x) \wedge R(x,x)) \}  $

(where $i$ is true and $h$ is false)

I know the properties of the logical (it can be true only, if the both logical expressions are true). So I have to check 16 pairs, where $a$ can be $1,2,3,4$ and the $x$ element is from the diagonal, and $x$ have to be true(in this case $i$)?

I think that the elements of this set is $(2,2),(4,4)$, are there any others?

Comment: I assume that $\alpha$ and $a$ are the same...

Comment: exactly, I've edited it

Comment: the condition $R(x,x)$ is satisfied only by $2$ and $4$: correct (see the diagonal.

Comment: Thus, the defining condition amounts to : $\{ a \mid R(a,2) \text { or } R(a,4) \}$

Comment: If so, also $3$ is in the set, because we have $R(3,4)$ and $R(4,4)$.

Comment: after rethinking the problem, I got the following 4 pairs: $R(1,4) \wedge R(4,4), R(2,2) \wedge R(4,4), R(3,4) \wedge R(4,4), R(4,4) \wedge R(4,4)$

Comment: so the elements of the set are: $(1,4),(2,2),(3,4),(4,4)$ Can be my solution correct?

Comment: Silly question; why $i$ and $h$ ? What is wrong with $T$ and $F$ or the "universal" $1$ and $0$ ?

Comment: my professor is using this notation, it's a really good question

Comment: Maybe they are "meaningful" in Hungarian ?

Comment: true=igaz, false=hamis

Comment: No, elements of this set are *not* pairs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you write: "so the elements of the set are: $(1,4)$, $(2,2)$, $(3,4)$, $(4,4)$".

This is not correct. If $X$ is your set, then the elements of $X$ are elements of $\underline{4}$, not pairs of elements of $\underline{4}$. In fact, $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$, since when $a$ takes on each of these values, we can find an $x$ such that $R(a,x)\land R(x,x)$. For example, $1\in X$, since when $a = 1$, we can pick $x = 4$, and we have $R(1,4)\land R(4,4)$.

One way to view the existential quantifier $\exists$ semantically is as "coordinate projection". That is, $\{(1,4), (2,2), (3,4), (4,4)\}$ is the set $W = \{(a,x)\in \underline{4}\times \underline{4} : R(a,x)\land R(x,x)\}$, and the set $X = \{a\in \underline{4} : (\exists x\in\underline{4})(R(a,x)\land R(x,x))\} = \{1,2,3,4\}$ is the projection of $W$ to the $a$ coordinate: the set of elements of $\underline{4}$ which appear as the $a$ coordinate of a pair in $W$.